# prepend and display custom header widget area via php

Tags: php, wordpress, prepend

so in my functions.php i have a hook as per theme documentation in prepending content before the body. i also create a widget area, which i'd like to be the prepend content, as follows:

```
// create custom header widget area
function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );

// prepend and display custom header widget area
add_action( 'before', 'uncode_child_hook_before' );
function uncode_child_hook_before(){
echo <?php

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>;
}
```

something must be off with my syntax- i'm a total php novice. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few bugs in there. Below are two examples... the first corrects the bugs in your code and the second is just another way to write the same thing I did in the correction:

```
// prepend and display custom header widget area
add_action( 'before', 'uncode_child_hook_before' );
function uncode_child_hook_before(){
    // open if statement
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) :

    // close php for html
    ?>
        <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php  // re open php

    // close if statement
    endif; 
}
```

Alternatively you could write this like below:

```
// prepend and display custom header widget area
add_action( 'before', 'uncode_child_hook_before' );
function uncode_child_hook_before(){
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) {
        echo '<div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">';
            dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `<?php do_action('before') ?>` in your `index.php`?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/